# TCS34725 color sensor readings fluctuate when interfacing with PIC16

Tags: pic, xc8

I am trying to read the values of the TCS34725 color sensor with a PIC16 through I2C. Currently, I am continuously polling the clear register on the TCS. However, every 10 or so times I read the value in the clear register, I get a random drop in the readings. For example, a set of consecutive readings may be [17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 14, 15, 16, 17 ...], repeating.

I have tried interfacing with an Arduino Uno in this same situation and get a consistent reading of 17.

I would like to eliminate the drop in the readings.

The code I have in XC8 for reading the TCS is as follows

```
void read_colorsensor(void){
unsigned char color_low[4];
unsigned char color_high[4];
int i;
I2C_Master_Start();
I2C_Master_Write(0b01010010);   //7bit address 0x29 + Write
I2C_Master_Write(0b10110100);   //Write to cmdreg + access&increment clear low reg
I2C_Master_Stop();

I2C_Master_Start();     //Repeated start command for combined I2C
I2C_Master_Write(0b01010011);   //7bit address 0x29 + Read
color_low[0] = I2C_Master_Read(1);
color_high[0] = I2C_Master_Read(0);
I2C_Master_Stop();
color[0] = (color_high[0] << 8)|(color_low[0]);
return;
}
```

Comment: And what happens, if instead of polling, you wait just a little more than the minimum necessary acquisition+conversion time (must be in the datasheet)? Do you have artificial lights nearby? E.g. fluorescent lights, computer screen? Do you have an oscilloscope to verify that the supply voltage is stable and clean? (Bad layout with the PIC may cause significant noise on the power/ground lines. Do you have the required bypass capacitors? Close to the supply pins?

Comment: The given integration time for the color sensor is 2.4ms, and currently I am waiting 3ms between polls. I have also tried waiting larger amounts of time, upwards of 100ms, but still I get the same result. The system I am testing the color sensor in right now is isolated from nearby lights, and the stable reading I get when I use an Arduino reflects that. I don't have an oscilloscope unfornatley, but I am fairly confident that the supply voltage is stable (using power supply from wall). I'm not sure what you mean by bypass capacitors, sorry.

Comment: The bypass capacitor is a tipically 100 nF ceramic capacitor as close to the Vcc (+ supply) pin and the GND pin as possible. If there are more Vcc pins far from each other, all of them needs capacitors. By briefly checking the datasheet it says nothing about it, but it does not mean that it can be omitted! For sensitive analog circuits (as the ADCs in you IC) it is not uncommon to use more capacitors parallel, i.e. 10 nF, 100 nF, several uF. The lager one serves as a bulk energy storage, the smaller ones provide noise filtering at different ferquencies. Try googling for ADC supply decoupling.